# Compressing data before sending it - controll characters?

Tags: c++, c, tcp, zlib

In a multiplayer game setting, I was going to use zlib to compress larger strings before sending them. I placed the resulting data back into strings, which are to be sent as byte streams using TCP.

My problem is, that I need to place control characters into the string as well. For example, I need to add the original string length (in plain text) to the front of the compressed string, and seperate it from the compressed data using some symbol, like "|".

But I can't find a way of knowing which bytes are actual content and which bytes are control characters. Are there any characters that a zlib-compressed-string will never contain (besides 0, which I can't use since it marks the end of a c-string) which I can use to seperate "metadata" and "compressed data"?

Comment: Why do you need to separate the length from the remaining data??

Comment: Why do you need the length in plain text? Isn't it simpler to use binary format?

Comment: Put the length of the compressed data in front of it, to know when your data ends and a new message type starts?

Comment: I used the compress and uncompress functions defined in zlib.h. The latter needs a buffer of the correct length for the resulting original string, and I wanted to send that along for simplicity's sake. Since the structure I have implemented for sending and receiving data currently uses strings (which I need for other values), I wanted to pack the compressed data into such a string. But I'm open for suggestions, if there are better methods. By "using binary format", do you mean always using the first (two) bytes to contain the length?

Comment: @user1781290, that's what I want to do, yes. But I don't know how to seperate the length from the actual data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control both creation of compressed blobs and decompression of them, you can prepend the size to the compressed data (prrobably by reserving some bytes at the beginning of the buffer), and then when decompressing skip the size and pass the pointer to compressed data to the decompression utility. This way you don't have to worry about messing up your compressed data with the size: the decompression code never sees the bytes that carry the size information.

Comment: Yes, this would do what I want. Then I can treat everything that comes in the string after the compressed data as a "normal" ascii string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no byte values that cannot be contained in a zlib stream.  However a zlib stream is *self-terminating*.  By simply using `inflate()` to decompress the stream, you will find the end when it returns `Z_STREAM_END`.  The bytes not consumed by `inflate()` are the next bytes immediately after the zlib stream.  Upon completion of decompression you know both how many compressed data bytes there are in the stream, as well as how many uncompressed bytes were generated.

If you are simply processing your entire stream, with the zlib stream imbedded, sequentially, then there is no need to store either the compressed or uncompressed lengths anywhere.  That information is inherent in the zlib data.  You would only need to store such data if you had a need to process your stream non-sequentially, or with the desire to access other data in stream after the zlib data without having to decompress the zlib stream.

Comment: Hm, I did not know the length can be derived from the stream. Then I need to switch to inflate(), though, which I wasn't doing so far.
Can there be zeros in the compressed stream as well? Because strings are zero-terminated - I might run into problems then.

Comment: Yes, there can be zeros.  _All_ byte values will appear in a sufficiently long stream.  If you know where the zlib stream starts, then there can be no confusion.

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing the compression?  If you're piping the output
through an external program, there's not much you can do, but if
you're using something internal, like a compressing streambuf,
you should be able to output to the original streambuf when
necessary.  With filtering streams from `boost::iostream`, for
example, you can write the length, then push the compression
stream, write the data to be compressed, then pop the
compression stream, and continue writing plain text.  (You may
have to insert a judicious flush here and there, before changing
the filter stack.)  Or you should be able to compress the parts
you want to compress into a buffer, and use
`std::ostream::write` to output them.