# Serialization via pickle/eval and zlib

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, zlib

I wish to compress a string using `zlib` and append it to a text message as a string. I have a couple of issues with it:

a. Is there a problem to combine "binary" string with normal string? For example, is there any problem sending via socket a string that looks like that:

```
MSG 10=12 20=x\x9c+(\xc0\x00\x00S3\x08Q 33=hansz
```

I ask it since when opening files one usually declares whether he intends to read at binary mode or not, and I never fully understood that.

b. Can I be sure that some characters will not appear in the compressed string? For example, if the compressed string will include some char sequence like `x\x9c 33=eve`, I'll have trouble parsing the message properly. If I know that whitespaces will never appear in a `zlib` compressed string, I can do some string split; If I know that quotes and apostrophes do not appear, I might use `shlex` split.

c. My intention is to use either `zlib.compress(str(obj))` or `zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(obj))` as kind of pickling, and use either `eval(zlib.decompress(s))` or `pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(s))` for unpickling. Do you think it makes sense? The first idea is less safe (as `eval` is never that safe), but it's an inner system, so I'm ok with it, and on the other hand the compressing turns out to be shorter on most cases, and as quick. Do you think it's a good practice?

d. The reason I wish to have these messages short is that I wish to send them later via socket. I am not proficient with sockets, however, I know these tend to read small (4k?) buffers, so I try to make my messages not much longer than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. The Problem with combining bytes and a unicode string is the following: There are more letters that 255. So historically, hundreds of encodings were created to put different alphabets into one byte.

```
>>> print b'\xE4'.decode('cp1251') # russian d
д
>>> print b'\xE4'.decode('cp1252') # german ae
ä
```

The letters have different meaning. To not loose the meaning of these letters, you use unicode.

```
>>> print u'\u00e4\u0434'
äд
```

However when you see bytes then you may not know the encoding. So you can not combine unicode and bytes straight away because one byte may be different letters.

Use `'UTF-8'` as encoding for the next years. It uses more than one byte if necessairy and stores all letters.

b. zlib takes bytes and outputs bytes. It can contain any byte.

c. `zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(obj))` and  `pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(s))` is totally fine. Pickle takes objects and returns bytes. You can save and store more objects than with `zlib.compress(repr(obj))` and `eval(zlib.decompress(s))`. `pickle` is as safe as `eval`. If you need save evaluation have a look at `import ast` `ast.literal_eval` or use `json` instead of `pickle`.

d. Make sure to know when a message ends and another message starts. I think you can use `zlib.decompressobj` for this. Otherwise zib can get confused. Sockets can send much more that 4k bytes. The buffer means that a socket saves up to 4k bytes and does not want to receive more until you take bytes out of the buffer. If you use TCP you can send endless streams of bytes and nothing is lost.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20804632/1565828), a compressed string may contain any byte, so the real answer for (b) is probably no. That's problematic, as it means I have no natural way to embed a compressed string within a "normal" message protocol.

Comment: I edited the answer. The answer you showed me already answers [how to embed a zlib compressed string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20804632/1320237) into a stream. `zlib.decompress(zlib.compress('hallo') * 2) == 'hallo'`. The `zlib.decompressobj` object knows how many bytes it read until the end of the compression.